# Passing client data into url express routes

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I am new to Node/Express, but I am converting my jQuery/Bootstrap app into an app with a node backend for routing and other server side tasks. Currently when a user clicks on a link, it will pass data into the url that I then grab when I get to the new page. Like this:

```
$("#parking_icon").on("click", function() {
        window.location = "_views/parkingLot.html?37.415912?-121.897520";
    });
```

I then grab and use that data on my `parkingLot.html` page. Like this:

```
var urlQuery = window.location.search.substring(1);
var mapLatLon = urlQuery.split("?");
var centerCoords = [parseFloat(mapLatLon[1]), parseFloat(mapLatLon[0])];
```

Now that I am trying to convert to using express routes, I am not exactly sure how to accomplish this. (I have about 20 buttons similar to the one above that all pass different coordinates in). I know I could accomplish this by creating a separate route for each of them similar to this:

```
    app.get('/parkingLot?37.415912?-121.897520', function(req, res) {
    res.render('parkingLot', {
        title: 'testing ParkingLotPage'
        });
    });
```

But it seems like there has to be an easier way. Should I not be using an `app.get()` at all? I am sure this is a noob question so please forgive me, as I am new to working with Node/Express. I am using the ejs templating engine if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think a little more abstractly, if you have a route for `/parkinglot` with a query string, then we can work with that query string directly on the route.

```
app.get('/parkinglot', (req, res) => {
  let lat = req.query.lat;
  let long = req.query.long;

  res.render('parkinglot', {
    title: '',
    data: {
      lat: lat,
      long: long
    }
  });
});
```

Make sure you're properly constructing your query string with the `key=value` syntax beginning with `?` and all Key-Value pairs separated by an `&`

```
$("#parking_icon").on("click", function() {
    window.location = "_views/parkingLot?lat=37.415912&long=-121.897520";
});
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the quick response. I did not think it would be THAT easy, I said I was new to this.. For the query string, why is that correct vs the way I had it (`?37.415912?-121.897520`) just curious. Does it actually matter or is that just best practice?

Comment: @AustinTruex yes it does matter, otherwise the query string parser won't be able to parse the query string passed.